# Why is Feynman-Kac formula applicable in Burgard-Kjaers PDE paper?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, cva, feynman-kac, dva

In the paper Partial Differential Equation Representation of Derivatives with Bilateral Counterparty Risk and Funding Costs by Burgard and Kjaer, they say we may formally apply the Feynman-Kac theorem to equation 29 which gives equation 30.

Equation 29 in the article is:

$\delta_{t} U + A_tU - rU = (1-R_{B})\lambda_B \text{min}(V+U,0) + (1-R_{C})\lambda_C \text{max}(V+U,0) + s_F \text{max}(V+U,0),$

with boundary condition $U(T,S) = 0$.

Here $A_t$ is the differential operator given by:

$A_t V = \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 S^2 \partial^2_{S} V + (q_s - \gamma_s) S \partial_S V$.

Not caring about technical conditions concerning function growth and similar in Feynman-Kac formula, what is the motivation that the Feynman-Kac formula is applicable here?

The Feynman-Kac formula is usually stated for the case of a function $U$, where we don't have any maximum or minimum functions applied.

E.g. in Karatzas-Shreve: Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus on page 268 we have this version:

$\partial_{t} U + \frac{1}{2}\partial_{S}^2 U - kU= g$.

How it is possible to transform the equation 29 such that it can be applied to the Feynman-Kac formula as stated e.g. in Karatzas-Shreve's book? Or where can you find a reference to a version of Feynman-Kac formula which closely resembles equation 29?

Comment: By "formally" they mean in this case that they (like many other applied scientists) don't worry about too much mathematical rigor. In the worst case the coefficients are silently assumed to please the rigorists . In a paper like that the authors have other stuff to worry about.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I rephrased the question to better explain that we can assume without proof that the coefficients satisfies whatever technical conditions are necessary for the Feynman-Kac formula.

Comment: On p. 268 of Karatzas & Shreve they must be using Brownian motion which -as we know- is related to the backward heat equation $\partial_tU+\frac12\partial_S^2U=0\,.$ A few chapters later the give the Feynman-Kac version for the solution of an SDE that is related to a more general PDE with differential operator $A_t\,.$ I think all other terms in the Burgard-Kjaer equation can be subsumed into KS's function $g\,.$

Comment: Thanks a lot Kurt G for the new answer and the reference to Feynman-Kac formula on page 366 in Karatzas-Shreves book! If we set V=0 we can as a special case get the PDE: $\delta_{t} U + A_t - rU = s_F \text{max}(U,0)$. This is a non-linear PDE, so this is an argument against the possibility to transform this into the formula 7.12 on page 366 in Karatzas-Shreves book with some particular choice of the function g. Would be very interesting with a detailed argument why this is possible.

Comment: The proofs in KS show the steps that you need to perform. BK wrote "nonlinear" integral equation before their (30) so they must have been aware of this and kept the nonlinear terms in the RHS of (30). Erasmus of Rotterdam used to say: "aquila non capit muscas."

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!